# Figuring out JSON memory leaks in Django

Tags: python, json, django, heroku, memory-leaks

I am using Python 3 and Django 3.1.4 for a web application hosted on Heroku. I started experiencing R14 and R15 errors related to memory quota exceeding.

The application involves a lot of API calls with large JSON data being sent to the client side via `JSONResponse`

I followed some online resources to run `tracemalloc` for some of the views.

```
        tracemalloc.start()

        # ... run your application ...

        snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
        top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')

        print("[ Top 10 ]")
        for stat in top_stats[:10]:
            print(stat)
```

I refreshed the page and I found this pattern.

Refresh 3:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py:353: size=290 MiB, count=3399976, average=89 B
```

Refresh 4:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py:353: size=406 MiB, count=4759963, average=89 B
```

Refresh 5:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py:353: size=522 MiB, count=6119933, average=89 B
```

Refresh 6:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py:353: size=638 MiB, count=7479913, average=89 B
```

With each refresh, the size increases. It even goes beyond 1000 MiB. Can it be concluded that there is a memory leak with the way JSON data is being handled?

How can I fix this problem?

**Update**

I ran load testing for all the API calls on the page using loader.io. Did not find any memory leak on Heroku. But as soon as I started browsing the page, it started showing a memory leak.